# Losing custom fields on work items when switching to new web form

Tags: tfs

I have several projects with custom fields in some of the work items.  Usually it is just a field that stores a string or int.  When I switch to the new web form view I cannot see my custom fields any more.  How do we edit the new web form view so that we can see the fields.

I tried using the process editor without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to export the process template's work item type definition and update the `WebLayout` section.

Ref:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/customize-wit-form?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 0):

The new work item form has a [simplified XML layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/weblayout-xml-elements?view=azure-devops) which is very easy to modify. The page, section, group and control elements map directly to what you see on the form.

When the new form is enabled [you can export your work item type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/customize-wit-form?view=azure-devops) to see the new layout automatically added in the WebLayout node.

Check the following blog for more information of new form:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/new-work-item-form-in-tfs-2017/